# Where can I find which properties are available in each Exchange Web Services version?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

First of all, I have pretty much no experience with developing Exchange Web Services-based applications.

I am developing an application that uses EWS Managed API to connect to an Exchange server. I need to support multiple Exchange versions, as I can't know in advance what version the server I'll be connecting to is running.

I was reading this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633705(v=exchg.80).aspx, and in the Unsuccessful Versioning part, it's written:

> The EWS Managed API will throw an exception if the example is run because the IsAssociated property on the EmailMessage object is not available in Exchange 2007 SP1.

My question is: is there a list of which properties are available (or unavailable) in each Exchange version?

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that the EWS `ExchangeVersion` (schema version) is not the same as the Service Version, on which Exchange is running.

Microsoft says:

> [...]applications designed against earlier versions of EWS will work, in most cases, with later versions of EWS, and applications that target later versions of EWS will work if the same functionality was included in an earlier version.

You can find further information about schema versioning and your requested feature set per schema version here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn741586(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no list of properties that i know off probably the closest would  be if you look at the EWS Managed API source https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/tree/154dbc66ac018d861c73ce489839cd9f58a1b0cd/ComplexProperties .

There are strongly typed properties which Microsoft have made available on the EWS objects and you can also access the underlying extended properties these strongly type properties refer to (or that no strongly type property exists). Just because a property isn't strongly typed in a certain version of EWS doesn't mean its not accessible its just you need to use another method more on that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn467898(v=exchg.150).aspx

There is a list of which EWS operations are available in which versions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb409286(v=exchg.150).aspx which is generally the more important. (Eg FAI Folder Associated Item traversals where first introduced in 2010 hence why isAvailble isn't in 2007).